# What will happen when run package between different ROS distributions?

Tags: ros, master

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I run groovy package on host and connect to PR2's fuerte master,
what will happened?

Is this action will cause some fault?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63655/what-will-happen-when-run-package-between-different-ros-distributions?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2013-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This works most of the time, provided the messages exchanged between nodes have not changed. Let's say you have message type A on fuerte on the "/whatever" topic and try to send it to a node in a groovy environment. If message type A for groovy is exactly the same, everything should work. If OTOH there has been a change to the message (let's say a std_msgs/Bool has been added to it for some reason) you will get a error complaining about the md5 sums for messages not being the same.

I'm not aware of other caveats right now and have been using a mixed fuerte/groovy setup extensively in the past few months.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1